# Remove unwanted row in csv with python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file that with name, address, and phone number

But in phone number, some address inserted, i want to delete those row of the phone number, please check this screenshot, then you will know the issue:

[image: Screenshot from csv]

Comment: Could you please provide a subset of your csv for testing?

Comment: You're going to have to read the file, iterate through the rows, and write the "good" rows back to disk.  You could try matching the phone number with a regex like `\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{3}`, depending on how varied your data is.

Comment: Please provide code showing what you have tried so far.  If it were not for the python, I could give you a single line solution using grep.

Comment: @VitorSRG,  It is bad enough the post contains live data.  It is obvious what he is asking for and how the data is shifted.

Comment: I need to solve it with python, coz, i have large amount of data like this, the CSV file exactly what i showed in in the screenshot,

Comment: Posting text instead of an image means we don't have to manually type in test data.  It's a courtesy, and isn't hard to cut-n-paste text instead of a screenshot.  Images are frowned upon in SO unless it is the only way to illustrate an issue (e.g. a graphics library problem).  It's also bad form to post real addresses and phone numbers on a public site.  Your customers might be pissed about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adapt the following code to your needs:

```
import csv
import re
import sys

data = list(csv.reader(sys.stdin))

column_to_validate = 4
pattern_to_match = r"^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}"

data = list(filter(lambda line: re.match(pattern_to_match, line[column_to_validate]), data))

csv.writer(sys.stdout).writerows(data)
```

Comment: You are welcome! Please, vote or accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers